# How to make an object continue moving on one axis although it's velocity is blocked on the other one

Tags: javascript, game-physics

Title says it all, but an example just to make it clearer what I mean:

An object have a velocity of x: 10, y: 10, so it moves diagonal down to the right. Now lets say the object already is at the right border of the passable area, but with plenty of room beneath it. I would like the object to move directly south (y:10) and discard the x-axis.

But I'm not sure how I would be able to achieve that?

```
class MovementComponent
{
  constructor(subject, collisionHandler, speed)
  {
    this.subject = subject;
    this.collisionHandler = collisionHandler;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
  }

  affectVelocity(axis, positive)
  {
    var force = new Vector2();
    if (axis == "X") {
      force = (positive) ? new Vector2(this.speed, 0) : new Vector2(-this.speed, 0);
    } else if (axis == "Y") {
      force = (positive) ? new Vector2(0, this.speed) : new Vector2(0, -this.speed);
    }
    this.velocity.add(force);
  }

  update()
  {
    if (!this.velocity.isZero()) { // No reason to run collision code when the object isn't moving.
      this.subject.position.add(this.velocity);
      if (!this.collisionHandler.canObjectBeHere(this.subject)) {
        this.subject.position.subtract(this.velocity);
        this.getCloseAsPossible(0.9);
      }
    }
    this.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0); // Reset the velocity to get a full stop when no keys are down. This is instead of applying friction. 
  }

  getCloseAsPossible(velocityModifier)
  {
    this.velocity.multiply(velocityModifier);
    this.subject.position.add(this.velocity);
    if (!this.collisionHandler.canObjectBeHere(this.subject)) {
       this.subject.position.subtract(this.velocity);
       this.getCloseAsPossible(velocityModifier - 0.1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to lock the x-axis after it passes a certain value. Let´s say the object is colliding the screen right corner as you said:

if your screen size is 800x600, you are probably updating your objects position +10 everytime you re-render to give the motion effect. Once your object reaches, `screenWidth - objectWidth` you stop adding 10 to the x-axis of the object`s position. That way, since you`re constantly adding 10 to the y-axis, your object will automatically "fall" on the screen. You can stop adding 10 to the y-axis when it reaches `screenHeight - objectHeight` which is the max y-axis position your object should be able to reach before it leaves the screen.

Comment: So as I see it, I need to expand my collision logic, so I can detect which direction the collision comes from, so I can lock that axis. ?

Comment: That's the idea. Just don't look at it as "direction". Every object on your screen will have a bounding box, let's say..a rectangle. Now, imagine that rectangle having 4 points on each corner and none of those points can cross the bounding box of the other colliding object (or screen). It's more a matter of "position per frame" than the direction they come from